# Binding 2 or more textboxes of a user control into a DGV. Only the first textbox works

Tags: binding, textbox

I have a problem with data binding my user control into a DGV. When I bind into only 1 textbox of my control, it works. However when I bind more than 1 textbox, only the first works. Please help. I am a C# beginner. Below is the code.

- I created Window Form app (named Test100)
- I added a user control "MyBox" into the project Test100, I added 2 textboxes into it (textBox1 and textBox2)
- In the MyBox.cs, I have the following:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  namespace Test100
  public partial class MyBox : UserControl
  {
      public string Box1
      {
          get
          {
              return textBox1.Text;
          }
          set
          {
              textBox1.Text = value;
          }
      }

      public string Box2
      {
          get
          {
              return textBox2.Text;
          }
          set
          {
              textBox2.Text = value;
          }
      }
      public MyBox()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }
  }
  ```
- After building, I opened my Form 1 and: added the MyBox control into my Form1, added a DGV into Form 1, added a button for refreshing the Form. The data list is produced directly in the Form1.cs. The Form1.cs is listed below:

  ```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
      private List<Track> trackList = new List<Track>();
      public Form1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          trackList.Add(new Track
          {
              TrackID = 1234,
              Name = "Name1111"
          });
          trackList.Add(new Track
          {
              TrackID = 5678,
              Name = "Name2222"
          });
          trackList.Add(new Track
          {
              TrackID = 9012,
              Name = "Name333"
          });
          BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
          bindingSource1.DataSource = trackList;
          dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

          myBox1.DataBindings.Add("Box1", dataGridView1.DataSource, "TrackID");
          myBox1.DataBindings.Add("Box2", dataGridView1.DataSource, "Name");

      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          this.Refresh();
      }
  }
  public class Track
  {
      public int TrackID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- After start debugging, I changed the Box1 value and pushed the button1, the TrackID on the DGV changed with the value I changed. However, when I changed the value of Box2 and pushed the button1, the Name column on DGV did not change but the Box2 returned to the original value.
- If I bind only the Box2, then Box2 will work.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: your code in question solved my problem! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Never mind. I found that this is a known issue that MS recognized from 2004 and fixed in .Net 1.1.
        http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812918
However I am using VS 2010 and doing Winform, I tried to apply the fix that MS fixed for this issue and it works. Thank you for reading.